# Wrong reference in ListView Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

[image]
Hi everyone,

I have a issue that stuck me 2 day, As you see the image, I start ONLY process #1 and update process to process bar but when I scroll down I see that another "process bar" run, It has the same process status as my first one (#1). I guess that my`ListView` items are reused and it use my process bar too, Does any one meet that problem? I also attach code as below,

Thank for your reading

```
    class gridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String currentText = list.get(position);
        View cell = convertView;
        if(cell==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gird_tiem, null);
              ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
              viewHolder.text = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
              viewHolder.button = (Button) cell.findViewById(R.id.button);
              viewHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) cell.findViewById(R.id.process);
              cell.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

         final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) cell.getTag();
         holder.text.setText(currentText);
         holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                processManager.onAddItemClick(100, holder.progressBar);
            }
        });
        return cell;
    }


}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public Button button;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
  }
```

//My Process Manager

```
public class ProcessManager {

Activity activity;

public ProcessManager(Activity activity) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
}

int temp;
public void onAddItemClick(final int tasks, final ProgressBar cell) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0;i<tasks;i++){
                temp = i;
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

                thread.run();
                try {
                    thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        cell.setProgress((temp*100)/tasks);
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    }).start();



}
```

//My item is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XXXX" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Process"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:focusable="false" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/process"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100" />
```

//my Grid view

Comment: could you post the xml layout where your progressBars are inside?

Comment: You should revise your code in the `onAddItemClick()` method. The items start the progress on their own because you assume the referenced `ProgressBar` is distinct for each row, which is not true as the `ListView` recycles rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) cell.getTag();
```

in an `else` bracket after your `if(cell==null)` statement. Otherwise it's going to create children from the tag every time (recycling views).

Comment: I already know that, but I want it better performance and It will lost view if orientation changes

Comment: You will always lose your data when orientation changes, no matter what you do because the Activity is restarted. And no, you will not lose performance using what's suggested. In fact it's better in this case to use an `else` than not.

Comment: If you don't use `else`, then you might have to get rid of the `if` also, taking away the advantages of view recycling.

Answer (score -1):

Try to not to override TextView from Holder so

```
 if TextView == null
```

then get the TextView, else only return it.

Comment: No, you still need to set the data even if convertView != null

Comment: I didn't mean ConvertView == null, but TextView, so, for example, "text" from the ViewHolder.

Comment: text can never be null from the ViewHolder.

Comment: Because in this case it is always changed for the new (not correct) one. The author should avoid it and then everything will be ok.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean... If you mean what Wenger means, then yes.

Comment: I mean tai.tran2008, because he on every ListView refresh update the `TextView text` and other views from the ViewHolder.